# Link de torrent (magnet) com contador

Tags: php

Oi, tem como fazer download de links magnet via php como se fosse o modo normal?

Preciso contar quantas vezes o arquivo foi baixado. Tentei `fopen()`, `file_get_contents()` e `header("Location: ")`, que também e não deu certo:

```
Warning: fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\gamepatch\download2.php on line 4
```

e também

```
Warning: file_get_contents(magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ed4fad95b4cb): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\gamepatch\download2.php on line 4
```

Tentativa:

```
<?php
   include "bd_connect.php";

   $arquivo = $_GET["arquivo"];
   header("Location: $arquivo");
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A página do link ficaria assim:

```
<?php
   $link = urlencode( 'magnet:?xt=urn:btih:ed4fad95b4cb' );
   echo '<a href="contador.php?link='.$link.'">Clique para baixar</a>'
?>
```

E a página `contador.php`, assim:

```
<?php
   $link=$_GET['link'];
   ... código do seu contador vai aqui ...
   header( "Location: $link" );

?>
```

Partindo destes modelos, basta acrescentar a lógica desejada, ou base de dados de links nas páginas dos links para download e do contador.

Comment: valew!!!!!!!!!!